# Install VSCode as a non-root user on a Linux distribution?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the de-facto approach to install VSCode on a Linux distribution e.g., Fedora as a non-root user? In other words, I want to install VSCode without using `sudo` permissions? Is there a way to `git clone` the repo and use it?

Any pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that downloading the `.rpm` file and running:

`rpm2cpio the_file_name.rpm | cpio -idv`

from the directory where it is downloaded will unpack VSCode's contents. Then, exporting the path to `bin/code` is sufficient.

Answer (score 14):

download this file: https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-x64
extract it and then just start vscode.

To start vscode:
go to VSCode-linux-x64 directory and run this command

```
./code
```

Comment: If it fails to run, adding --no-sandbox solved the problem for me: ```./code --no-sandbox```. (NOTE: this seems to be an unsecure workaround)

Comment: Just adding a one-liner here to download it from the command line:

`wget --user-agent=Mozilla --content-disposition -E -c "https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-x64"`